# View with data from many databases

Tags: python, database, django, distributed

I'm building site in django, which lists items of many suppliers. Each supplier has own big database and make changes quite often. I have to be aware of all changes in no more than 60 minutes. There are about 10m items to display. How to implement all that in a efficient way?

Comment: Wow.  That's a broad question that involves many technical choices, each of which is a separate, deep and complex technical discussion.  As asked, this question cannot easily be answered.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your application has a pretty ugly architecture. Try to refactor it or you will have troubles.

Anyway, you can try to cache your suppliers' data to your own database (single) and save some resources.